# How to process large csv files efficiently using shell script, to get better performance than that for following script?

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a large csv file `input_file` with 5 columns. I want to do two things to second column:

(1) Remove last character
(2) Append leading and trailing single quote

Following are the sample rows from `input_file.dat`

```
420374,2014-04-06T18:44:58.314Z,214537888,12462,1
420374,2014-04-06T18:44:58.325Z,214537850,10471,1
281626,2014-04-06T09:40:13.032Z,214535653,1883,1
```

Sample output would look like :

```
420374,'2014-04-06T18:44:58.314',214537888,12462,1
420374,'2014-04-06T18:44:58.325',214537850,10471,1
281626,'2014-04-06T09:40:13.032',214535653,1883,1
```

I have written a following code to do the same.

```
#!/bin/sh
inputfilename=input_file.dat
outputfilename=output_file.dat
count=1

while read line
do
  echo $count
  count=$((count + 1))
  v1=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1)
  v2=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2)
  v3=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f3)
  v4=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f4)
  v5=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f5)
  v2len=${#v2}
  v2len=$((v2len -1))
  newv2=${v2:0:$v2len}
  newv2="'$newv2'"
  row=$v1,$newv2,$v3,$v4,$v5
  echo $row >> $outputfilename
done < $inputfilename
```

But it's taking lot of time.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Use awk or sed for this kind of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=q substr($2,1,length($2)-1) q}1' input_file.dat
```

How it works:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` : set input and output field separator (`FS`, `OFS`) to `,`.
- `-v q="'"` : assign a literal single quote to the variable `q` (to avoid complex escaping in the `awk` expression)
- `{$2=q substr($2,1,length($2)-1) q}` : Replace the second field (`$2`) with a single quote (`q`) followed by the value of the 2nd field without the last character (`substr(string, start, length)`) and appending a literal single quote (`q`) at the end.
- `1` : Just invoke the default action, which is `print` the current (edited) line.

Comment: you need to also set `OFS`, otherwise the output won't be comma separated. For the rest, +1, well done!

Comment: @fedorqui Oh, you're right, nice catch! I'll update asap.